# Get query string parameter from URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, url, dom

I'm looking for a way to extract the query parameters and their corresponding values from a url.

For example. If I have the URL: `http://example.com/home?key=value`

How can I find the value of `key`

Comment: by window.location, the window of iframe

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function. It's inspired from [`riot.route.query()`](http://riotjs.com/api/route/)

`getQuery( [url] )` returns an object containing every *`key`, `value`* pair in the query of `window.location.href` or the optional `url` parameter.

```js
var iFrameUrls = [
    'http://www.kk.com/home/add.do?select=inputText',
    '?select=verifyText&this=foo%20bar',
    'http://www.kk.com/home/add.do?select=confirmText'
    ];

function getQuery(url) {
    var query = {},
        href = url || window.location.href;
        
    href.replace(/[?&](.+?)=([^&#]*)/g, function (_, key, value) {
        query[key] = decodeURI(value).replace(/\+/g, ' ');
    });
    
    return query;
}

for (var i = 0, l = iFrameUrls.length; i < l; i++)
  console.log( getQuery( iFrameUrls[i] ) );
```

Comment: hey Thank you. But we have multiple pages whose query parameter changes based on the page we are in (select=inputText, select=enterText) so we need one code to capture the current value from to find on which page we are in

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to retrieve from the URL?

Comment: www.kk.com/home/add.do?select=inputText  |                www.kk.com/home/add.do?select=verifyText  |                                                          www.kk.com/home/add.do?select=confirmText |                                             We have some steps in iframe with the above sample URLs. 1st page asks for input,2nd asks us to verify and 3rd gives us confirmation. Now if are able to capture the Target values from the iFrame URL we will know in which step the user is in

Comment: So you're looking for whether `select` = `inputText`, `enterText` etc.?

Comment: Yes Exactly! Justin

Comment: Because you're using an `iframe`, you'll need to use `document.querySelector('#iframeID').src` as the `url` parameter. Unless the script executing `getQuery` is in the `iframe`—than just use `getQuery()`

Comment: Yeah! Thanks Justin

Comment: @pradeep My pleasure.