# How do I activate a dynamic tab from another page in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a web page which has dynamic tabs from Bootstrap. I'm having problem in linking a tab's content from an external page.

I want to activate the menu 1 and menu 2 tab of the page below from an external link of another page.
Tried using href="index.html#menu1" but it doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>index</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Menu 1 activated.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Menu 2 Activated </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to [this answer about query string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42519491/3091563) and [this answer about to show Bootstrap's tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24343998), add the following script to your page and generate links on the other pages by using query string!

```js
function getQuery(url) {
  var query = {},
      href = url || window.location.href;
  href.replace(/[?&](.+?)=([^&#]*)/g, function (_, key, value) {
      query[key] = decodeURI(value).replace(/\+/g, ' ');
  });
  return query;
}

function getParam(name){
    var obj = getQuery();
    return obj[name];
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var target = getParam('target');
  $('.nav a[href="#'+target+'"]').tab('show');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>index</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Menu 1 activated.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Menu 2 Activated </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
use the following script and 
the link on the other pages should be like this: url?target=menu2 
without "#" 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```